# Reload Div SetInterval somente quando houver novo registro

Tags: jquery

Olá!

Gostaria de compreender como recarregar uma div somente quando um novo registro fosse realizado no banco de dados. O disparo dessa ação seria como em um setInterval, mas não a cada xxxsegundos, mas sim quando ocorresse o novo insert ou update,delete...

Por exemplo, mesmo com a tela do sistema parada, sem nenhuma ação, eu receberia a atualização dessa div quando outro usuário realizasse um novo registro em outra máquina com seu login.

Alguém já fez isso, ou sabe como???

Comment: Infelizmente essa mágica não existe, você vai ter que fazer a verificação do novo conteúdo pelo client, usando um interval ou disparo mecânico ou manter uma conexão ativa com o servidor como um socket para receber a notificação.

Comment: Mas com esse interval, digamos que a cada 30segundos... Terei uma sobrecarga no servidor, travando o sistema, não? E manter conexão como em um socket, como seria isso?